# Make it doesn't returns only 1 value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm doing a query with PHP to bring from the database only the value `user`, here's the function I'm using:

```
$sentence = $connection->prepare("
    SELECT DISTINCT user from users ORDER BY RAND()
");
$sentence->execute();
return $sentence->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

The variable `$sentence` is being used to make the SQL query. Then we execute the query and use `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` so the result is not repeated. When I show the result on the web, its only bringing 1 value, random but only one. How can I make so it brings the number I want of results?

Comment: `fetch()` only returns 1 row, look at `fetchAll()` for all of the rows (add a LIMIT to your SQL if you don't want all of the data).

Comment: When I change my `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` for a `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`, it marks `notice: array to string conversion`... What can I do? I've already looked for other ways to solve the problem but doesn't work, it keeps saying that

Comment: Array to string is because you've now got an array of results and presumably need to update the part of your code where you print out the data to deal with this.  Such as `$result[0]['value you're looking for'] `

Comment: Sorry, can you explain more clearly what do you mean with that?

Answer (score 1):

If you are only looking for a count of rows then just do a select count distinct.  That will give you a count of unique values.

Comment: I think op would also need to change the code to `fetchColumn`